# Can I use Redactor on my front end?

Tags: frontend

I'm building a simple user backend and I would like to use Redactor for a couple fields. I see Redactor is a commercial product.

1. When I pay for Craft Pro does that include a license to use Redactor?
2. From an implementation standpoint, can I use the libraries already available?

I guess I wouldn't mind loading in another version of redactor for my front end. But I'm mostly curious if my craft license covers a redactor license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brandon has answered this [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4225/how-do-i-enable-redactor-rich-text-editor-in-a-front-end-form/4238#4238).

tl;dr: technically possible, legally questionable, in practice not a good idea.

Comment: We heard back from Imperavi on the legal aspect of it.  Updated the answer [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4238/57).

Comment: Ahh! I searched before I posted this. Sorry for the dupe, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Derek But if you hadn't asked, we wouldn't have gotten the legal update (legally fine)