# How do I maintain paragraph formatting on textarea Guest Entries submission?

Tags: richtext, guest-entries

I have set up a guest entries form that receives data from the textarea snippet below and saves it into a rich text field.

```
<textarea name="fields[comment]" placeholder="Join the discussion..."></textarea>
```

When I view the entry on the front-end there is no formatting, but on the backend there is formatting. Then when I save the entry on the back-end, suddenly there is formatting on the front-end.

Is there anyway to bypass having to re-save the entry to get the desired formatting?

Comment: Is it a Rich Text field?

Comment: Yes. And when I view source in Redactor I can see paragraph tags that start to show up after I save the entry again.

Comment: Without using a JavaScript parser, not sure you'd be able to achieve what you're looking for. Unless of course you want to allow Redactor on the front-end. http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4225/how-do-i-enable-redactor-rich-text-editor-in-a-front-end-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RichText fields make use of the Redactor plugin library, which if I understand correctly, essentially parses line-breaks and wraps lines in properly formatted html `<p>` tags via javascript. However, when you save from the front-end, it doesn't have a chance yet to parse the data. Only when you view the data on the back-end and re-save does redactor get a chance to do it's thing.

- You could use redactor on the front-end, although this is not recommended for various reasons [as described here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4238/784).
- Or you could change the fieldtype to a regular textField and wrap everything in a `<pre>` tag in your template. `<pre>{{ entry.myTextField }}</pre>`
- Or you could parse the string yourself via javascript before submitting it, wrapping your own `<p>` tags (hopefully it won't get double encoded).

There might be other options as well.